# An error occurred in an after hook NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (AngularJS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec, angularjs, database-cleaner

I'm using Rails 3.2.13 with postgres, rspec 2.13, capybara 2.0.3 and database_cleaner 0.9.1. I'm also using AngularJS. I have a spec with js:true which tests the submission of a form (creating a standard rails model instance). The only thing that's maybe not standard Rails is that I submit this form via Ajax using AngularJS. Whenever the spec runs, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred in an after hook
  NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
  occurred at /Users/morgler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@pennyworth/gems/activerecord-    3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:310:in `replace'
```

The spec subsequently fails. To me it seems, this error occurs in the after hook when the database_cleaner runs. I got this in my spec_helper.rb:

```
config.before(:each) do
  if Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  else
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

The code to submit the form via AngularJS upon clicking the form's submit button is:

```
$scope.saveOrderProcess = (event) ->
  if $scope.orderProcess.id
    $scope.orderProcess.$update()
  else
    OrderProcess.create($scope.orderProcess)
```

Any idea, what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The root of my problem seems to be a totally different one:

I'm using deeply nested objects (order_process has order_steps has option_items). Rails needs these nested objects to be called "option_items_attributes" and so on. It seems, somewhere deep in my hash I failed to convert "option_items" into "option_items_steps".